# An error occurred while calling o95.getDynamicFrame. Unable to execute HTTP request in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am running an ETL job to transfer data from Amazon S3 to Redshift using AWS Glue. After the ETL job is created and run I'm getting the following error.

**An error occurred while calling o95.getDynamicFrame. Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to mybucketname.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 [mybucketname.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ip] failed: connect timed out**

Appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Please post your code.  It will give us a better idea what's causing the error